# Find an angle to accelerate at to most quickly go from one movement vector to another

Tags: calculus, geometry, physics

Okay, so this is with respect to game design, so that’s where I’m coming from (please try to use smol words, I am no mathematician)

I have a 2D space ship. Its velocity is defined by vector A, let’s say (1i,0j), and the ship’s current position is (0,0). I also have a point P, let’s define it as (0,3). I’m trying to figure out how to select an angle at which the ship can be constantly accelerated at a rate of 1 unit/sec^2 in order to go from traveling along vector A to having a velocity that is directed exactly at point P. Ideally, this angle would result in the ship reaching the correct vector before it crosses point P in order for it to have time to turn around and negatively accelerate.
I’m assuming I could find a way to plot a parabola using the calculus and stuff but it’s a little beyond me at the moment.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to STOP at P? Can acceleration be in any direction?

Comment: Sorry I now it’s confusing, I’m confused myself :p. Essentially I want the ship to go from where it currently is to P as fast as possible, and afaik, the fastest way to do this is to constantly accelerate in one specific magic direction. One problem is the ship needs to decelerate to come to a stop at P, so that would mean that there would be exactly 1 optimal direction. I suspect this is an optimization problem but I’m not good enough at calculus to figure it out. Hell I don’t even know if this is a plausible question but I’d thought I’d ask the math people on the inter webs

Comment: I suppose a way to start would be to just cancel the velocity that is lateral to the ships’s vector to P. Then the ship would only need to accelerate toward P and then slow down. It would take longer but then I guess I could brute force it by running the simulation and plotting values, but a more elegant solution would probably be better

Comment: And yes let’s say acceleration can be any direction. (The ship in reality would need to turn and point away from any direction it wanted to accelerate in, but that can be solved later)

Comment: Your desire for a CONSTANT angel is not feasible - you start by moving away and have FIXED acceleration in any desired direction, at a certain point you will need to choose another angel. You need to allow some flexibility - rethink your question.

Comment: May be that stopping at P will require quite maneuvering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this problem we will generalize the equation for acceleration in one direction. From kinematics, we know that:
$$x_f = x_0 + v_{x0}\,t + \frac{1}{2}\,a_x\,t^2$$
Solving for acceleration, we find that:
$$a_x = \frac{2\,(x_f - x_0 - v_{x0}\,t)}{t^2}$$
We will say that the initial position is always zero relative to the position of the ship, meaning that $x_0 = 0$. This simplifies our equation to:
$$a_x = \frac{2\,(x_f - v_{x0}\,t)}{t^2} = 2\,x_f\,t^{-2} - 2\,v_{x0}\,t^{-1}$$
In order to find the optimal acceleration, we must find the critical points for $t$ by taking the time derivative:
$$\frac{da_x}{dt} = -4\,x_f\,t^{-3} + 2\,v_{x0}\,t^{-2}$$
Looking at a graph, we can see that this is equal to zero only when $t = 2$ meaning:
$$a_x = \frac{2\,[x_f - v_{x0}\,(2)]}{(2)^2} = \frac{x_f - 2\,v_{x0}}{2}$$
This equation is the optimal acceleration required in a single direction to get to a desired location where $x_f$ is the distance from the ship to the destination and $v_{x0}$ is the initial velocity in the same direction. To find the magnitude and direction of the acceleration vector in 2D space:
$$a = \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y^2}$$
$$\theta = \arctan{\left(\frac{a_y}{a_x}\right)}$$
You should always check that the angle makes sense with the components of your acceleration vector. If they do not match up, you can usually add $180^{\circ}$ to your angle value.

Comment: This is a magic answer, as when putting it a game loop, it not only navigates to, but stops at point P. This is more than perfect for my purposes

Comment: Isn't $v_{x0}=1$?

Comment: It is in this scenario, but that was just just an arbitrary value. Having it be generic in this makes it usable for the space sim